# Cluster analysis on categorical variables

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to group different shark species by the type of gear with which they  are caught. So, I have the different shark species, and for each species, I have allocated the different gear types each one is likely to be caught by (three different columns - see table below).

This is a subset of a much larger dataset, and I would like to perform a cluster analysis to see which shark and ray species group together by the gear types with which they are caught. Does anyone have any ideas? I have not been able to find examples of cluster analyses solely on categorical variables.

[image: table describing the variables]

Comment: I would start out with maybe multinomial logit models, or by presenting the data as an contingency table and use correspondence analysis. To say more we would like more details, like number of observations, number of shark species, and wheather all observations correspond to one or mre ecoregions, ...

Comment: Your three variables are what are called _categorical multiple response set_ (three nominal variables, each next is "one more answer". Transform it to _dichotomous multiple response set_ consisting of binary variables. Each variable is a kind of gear and values are 1 ("applies") and 0 ("not applies"). Then select a distance or similarity measure for binary data -they are plenty different. Then do hierarchical clustering by any linkage method except maybe Ward, centroid or median which are not recommended with non-continuous data.

Comment: Chapter 15 in [this book](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9781498731782) is about correspondence analysis and clustering. Also search google scholar for "correspondence analysis and clustering"